# How to save time to conduct both grid search and k-fold cross validation for hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, cross-validation, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am planning to perform grid search with k-fold cross validation (CV) to optimise hyperparameters of LSTM. Let's say I have *n* hyperparamter combinations and defined *k*-fold CV. It means that I have to run LSTM *n x k* times, which can be computationally intensive.

Q1. is there any practical tip that can save time?

To save time, what if 1) I split the whole training data into test vs val (e.g., 80:20), no k-fold, and find optimal hyperparmeters; in this case *n x 1* runs, and 2) perform *k*-fold CV for LSTM only with the optical hyperparameter found from 1) to demonstrate overall performance of the selected LSTM? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

For big models, CV is not really feasible. So you should split your data in a train-val-test manner.

Grid search is also not the best approach, it is preferable to use random search, for why, see e.g. [here](https://blog.usejournal.com/a-comparison-of-grid-search-and-randomized-search-using-scikit-learn-29823179bc85).